# ExtJS: textfield allowBlank with conditions

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a `panel` with some `textfield` and `fieldcontainer` like this:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
    items: [{
        padding: '0 10 5 10',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'data',
        id: 'data',
        alType: 'data',
        labelWidth: 130,
        fieldLabel: i18n.get('label.data'),
        allowBlank: false,
        enforceMaxLength: true,
        maxLength: 8,
        minLength: 1,
        allowDecimals: false,
        allowExponential: false,
        invalidText: i18n.get('error.bad.data'),
        maskRe: /[0-9]/
    }, {
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        layout: 'hbox',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            padding: '0 10 5 10',
            width: 285,
            xtype: 'datefield',
            name: 'date',
            id: 'date',
            alType: 'date',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            labelWidth: 130,
            fieldLabel: i18n.get('label.date'),
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'timefield',
            padding: '0 10 5 15',
            width: 230,
            name: 'hour',
            id: 'hour',
            labelWidth: 80,
            fieldLabel: i18n.get('label.hour'),
            minValue: '00:00',
            maxValue: '23:00',
            format: 'H:i',
            increment: 60,
            anchor: '100%',
            allowBlank: false
        }]
    }]
});
this.callParent(arguments);
```

And I would like to add a condition for `allowBlank` :

- By default all `allowBlank` are `false`
- if there is a `data => allowBlank` for date and hour is `true`
- if there are a date and a `hour => allowBlank` for data is `true`

How can I do this please ?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you

Comment: Give some fiddle for your code

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why but the "Hello" is missing..

Comment: You should write a custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

**its very simple:**

get data in config or init method:

```
allowBlank:(data.rec.hour)?'true':'false';
```

> this will surely work.
>   if you want to use it in listeners like change or focus then,

```
onChangeCheckbox:function(cmp, newValue, oldvalue){  //it is recomended to use allowBlank in listners instead.
            var me=this,
            form=cmp.up('form'),
            field=form.down('#foldername'),
            field.allowBlank=!newValue;
               //(please set condition accordingly Above.)
        },
```

Comment: `allowBlank:(data.rec.hour)?'true':'false';` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:-

```
field.allowBlank = YOUR_DATA.allowBlank; // data => allowBlank
field.validateValue(field.getValue());
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `ViewModel`.

If you are using a standard MVC (Model View Controller), I will assume that you already know how to use a `controller`.

In your `controller`, the moment that you set your data:

**Controller code snippet :**

```
me.getViewModel().set('isThereData', data)
me.getViewModel().set('isThereDate', dateAndHour)
```

- Note: It's not necessary to initiate this variables on your `ViewModel`.

**In your View Code snippet:**

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'data',
    bind: {
        allowBlank: '{isThereDate}'
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Date and Hour',
    bind: {
        allowBlank: '{isThereData}'
    }
}
```

- Thru binding, the values you set on your `ViewModel` will be synchronized with the values on your `View`.
- Extjs automatically translates '{isThereData}' true if it is not empty.

Comment: `Ext.mixin.Bindable.applyBind(): Cannot bind allowBlank on Ux.combobox.SearchableComboBox - missing a setAllowBlank method.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var yourField  = Ext.getCmp('comboBoxID');
if(your_condition == true){
    Ext.apply(yourField,{allowBlank:true});
}else  {
    Ext.apply(yourField,{allowBlank:false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like below.

```
function setAllowBlank(field, allowBlank) {
  if (field.allowBlank != allowBlank) {
    Ext.apply(field, { allowBlank });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var field = Ext.getCmp('date');
setAllowBlank(field, true);
```

Comment: It should be like this (3rd line):
Ext.apply(field, {allowBlank: false}, {});

But for me still not helps for some reason...